# remove a button from application at runtime

Tags: xcode, button

I have a xcode/ipad application that adds buttons at runtime at the touch point on the screen.

Now I need to remove these button(s) at runtime by only using the x/y coordinates.

How do I accomplish this??

take care
tony

Answer (score 0):

not the best and fastest way to do it, but iterate over the parent view's control list, find out their relative x/y coordinates and remove them from the parent view